# Using Spring Yaml Configuration how can I specify a configuration for a combination of profiles

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

I would like to have a configuration set for a specific profile combination.
Ideally, something that looks like the following:

```
server: default
---
spring:
  profiles: prod
server: default-prod
---
spring:
  profiles: us-region, prod
server: us-region-server
```

My goal is to avoid having too much profiles for the one configuration I have. currently I have three stages ( alpha, pre-prod, prod), each one deployed on two regions, and I will have three separate instance types, I only need to set the configured server.